# Declarar e mostrar variáveis no Model MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Estou usando o padrão MVC, e preciso declarar o valor de uma variável dentro do arquivo model e acabei fazendo isso:

```
public $user_id = null;
public $user_name = "";
public $user_email = "";
public $user_is_logged_in = false;

public function doLoginWithPostData($user_name, $user_password) {
    ...
    $this->user_id = $result_row->id;
    $this->user_name = $result_row->username;
    $this->user_email = $result_row->mail;
    $this->user_is_logged_in = true;
    ...
}
```

Porém, quando estou tentando mostrar essas variáveis em um controller, simplesmente, aparece sem nenhum valor. 
Var_dump:

```
object(Model)#4 (5) { ["user_id"]=> NULL ["user_name"]=> string(0) "" ["user_email"]=> string(0) "" ["user_is_logged_in"]=> bool(false) ["db"]=> object(PDO)#3 (0) { } }
```

EDIT: Percebi que as informações só são perdidas quando mudo de página

Comment: se você quer fazer um login, deve salvar os dados em uma sessão ou cookie para que possa acess-a-los quando muda de página. O comportamento aí é o esperado, armazena e acessa enquanto esta classe está na memória. Recarregou, perdeu.

Comment: Então, deixar assim resolveria? http://pastebin.com/wZKw1VJH

Comment: Sim, claro que é um exemplo "solto", mas o conceito é esse,